# how to make the bash script portable?

Tags: bash, portability

I have written a bash script which is dependent on current folder structure,
What should I do to make it runnable in any other folder(become portable)?
let me explain more: I want the script to delete all the files in current directory that the script is running,
or to delete all the files that are in the parent folder,
what is the solution?

Comment: Please show us the script.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you want. If the program is in `/foo/bar`, and I run it from `/opt/bar/foo/foo`, you want it to work as if I ran it in `/foo/bar` and delete all the files in `/foo/bar`?

Comment: suppose that scrip is deleting all files in the directory that my bash script is running,if it is running in /foo/bar/ delete all the files in /foo/bar/* if I copy the script file to another folder like /xx/yy/ then to delete the files of /xx/yy/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

Add this to the top of your script to have it `cd` to the directory the script is installed at. Then you can use relative paths and they'll be relative to the script dir and not the user's `pwd`.

If for whatever reason `dirname` isn't available, here's an equivalent statement that uses `basename` instead.

```
cd "${0%%/$(basename "$0")}"
```

Comment: thanks john,but how should I write rm /foo/bar/* in my script so it will work everywhere?

Comment: You can write simply `rm *`

Comment: What system has basename but not dirname?

Comment: @glennjackman Good question. I have the basename version listed as an alternative to the dirname one in one of my scripts. I'm not sure what environment needed that workaround. The nearby comment says it was needed when scripting a Red Hat [Kickstart](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart) install... but if that was true it's no longer the case. I just tested RHEL 6.4 and both dirname and basename are available at Kickstart time.

Comment: dirname seems to work but I am not sure about $0,since I get below error when try to use your suggestion:  `No such file or directory` how can I test that $0 is working in my system?

Comment: finaly,I got it, the above line is not working ins cygwin,but it is fine in Solaris, thanks for John

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolute paths in your script.

Comment: Don't hate. The answer is correct and appropriate for the lack of additional information in the question, why downvote?

Answer (score 0):

we need more information to give you a proper answer...BUT some tips if you need to make it portable are to store any files that you need on a network share and simply make a new folder off of `/` such as `/temporaryScriptFolder/` and mount the network share to that empty folder, allowing you easy access to any resources that are necessary.